# How to make a else statements? Python

Tags: python

I want to run a code that just shows the unitsecond if unitfirst is selected volume.

```
#=== Label for 'Unit' & Combobox ===
lbl_unit = Label(main_frame, text='Unit', font=('arial',16,'bold'), fg='white',bg='dark blue')
lbl_unit.place(x=180,y=100)

unitfirst = ttk.Combobox(main_frame,textvariable=unitunit, font=('arial',16),width=10,state='readonly')
unitfirst['value'] = ('Select Unit','Volume','Length', 'Mass')
unitfirst.current(0)
unitfirst.place(x=280,y=100)


#=== Label for 'From' & Combobox ===
lbl_from = Label(main_frame, text='From', font=('arial',16,'bold'), fg='white',bg='dark blue')
lbl_from.place(x=180,y=150)

#=== combobox ==
unitsecond = ttk.Combobox(main_frame,textvariable=unitfrom, font=('arial',16),width=10,state='readonly')
unitsecond['value'] = ('Select Unit','ml','l')
unitsecond.current(0)
unitsecond.place(x=280,y=150)
```

I know that it needs else statements, but I don't familiar with them.

Comment: I recommend checking out the related section in the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x = int(input("Please enter an integer: "))
Please enter an integer: 42
>>> if x < 0:
...     x = 0
...     print('Negative changed to zero')
... elif x == 0:
...     print('Zero')
... elif x == 1:
...     print('Single')
... else:
...     print('More')
...
```

ref: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#if-statements